# duration between two columns with format hhmmss

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I determine the difference / duration between two columns, which have the following format:
HHMMSS.

Leading zeros are swallowed by the system (Oracle DB).
   0 o'clock is a "0".
   3 o'clock is "300".
   23:50 clock is "235000".

Whatever, 24:00 is also reported as "240000".
That means I have the column "Start" and the column "End".

How can you determine the duration using SQL?

Comment: 3 o'clock should be 30000. (HHMMSS with leading 0 trimmed) but in your question you mentioned that it is 300. Can you please explain?

Comment: Just to mention: minutes format mask is `MI`; `MM` is for **months**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the values to seconds using arithmetic:

```
select hhmmss, floor(hhmmss / 10000) * 60 * 60 + (mod(hhmmss, 10000) / 100) * 60 + mod(hhmmss, 100)
from (select 235000 as hhmmss from dual) x
```

Then subtract the seconds.  That will give you the duration in seconds.

With your column names, this would look like:

```
select ( (floor(end / 10000) * 60 * 60 + (mod(end, 10000) / 100) * 60 + mod(end, 100)) -
         (floor(start / 10000) * 60 * 60 + (mod(start, 10000) / 100) * 60 + mod(start, 100))
       ) as diff_seconds
```

To convert this back to a string, you can use `to_char()`:

```
select to_char(date '2000-01-01' + diff_seconds * interval '1' second, 'HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: Awesome! It works. Thanks Gordon. How can be the output a duration in format of HH:MM:SS?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the duration in hour/minutes/seconds using `to_date` as following:

```
Select round(
    (to_date(lpad(end,6,'0'),'HHMISS')
     - to_date(lpad(start,6,'0'),'HHMISS') ) * 24
     , 2) diff_in_hours 
       -- multiply it by another 60 to get diff in minutes (24*60)
       -- multiply it by another 3600 to get diff in seconds (24*3600)
  from your_table
```

To get the output in HHMISS just add it to sysdate

```
Select
        TO_CHAR(Trunc(sysdate) + (to_date(lpad(end,6,'0'),'HHMISS')
         - to_date(lpad(start,6,'0'),'HHMISS')) , 'HH:MI:SS') as diff_HHMISS
      from your_table
```

Cheers!!